# What's faster? (a+a vs 2*a and more)

Tags: c++, c, performance

In C/C++, I was wondering which is faster?

```
int a;
int b = a + a; // this
int b = 2 * a; // or this?
```

Also, is important the datatype? What about `long`? what about the number of times we add up?

(what about...)

```
long a;
long b = a + a + a +a;
long b = 4 *a;
```

Comment: Depends more on the CPU than the language.

Comment: This is easy to try using Stopwatch. Why don't you post what you've tried if you still don't know afterwards?

Comment: Any compiler from the last 25 years will compile `a + a` and `2 * a` identically into whatever is fastest on the target architecture.

Comment: ..oh, and you forgot about `a << 1`. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Trust your optimizing compiler.  It knows how to optimize for a specific CPU/architecture in ways that you will only be able to guess.  Without reference to a specific architecture, there is no meaning to statements like "is x faster than y?", because it all depends on a huge number of factors.

And as always with performance questions, measuring is going to answer the question more completely than us offering semi-informed opinions and guesses.

Comment: The question's example does not deserve a second thought but there are computations that the compiler cannot optimize because the optimized version is not strictly equivalent. Examples include replacing `x/2` by `x>>1` (only the programmer can do this if ey knows x≥0 or does not care about the difference when x≤0), `x/5.0` by `x*0.2`, and so on. The compiler cannot choose these optimizations by itself.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Good point in general, but bad examples (I'd prefer some higher-level optimizations to avoid the impression that such low-level issues are worth spending time on). When bit fiddling is of interest, you should be using an unsigned type and then `x/2` and `x>>1` are equivalent. And while floating point expression rewriting is a good example of an optimization changing results, compilers *do* perform that if asked to with the equivalent of `-ffast-math`.

Comment: @delnan Well my favorite example is `*p = 1; *q = 2; return *p + *q;` but the ensuing discussion about communicating information from the programmer to the compiler does not fit in a SO comment. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/07/25/On-the-redundancy-of-C99-s-restrict PS: **I** think that `-ffast-math` is a bad counter-example because it is like giving the compiler a license to mess up all floating-point computations, which is not the same as deliberately choosing that one particular computation can be made as `x*0.2` for its intended purpose.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, yes, I whole-heartedly agree that there are optimizations that one should be aware of and which would not be performed automatically by any sane compiler.  That said, it's often the absolute last resort to start making such micro-optimizations, and significantly greater gains are often found by the usual approaches like algorithmic optimization, or removing uses of aliasing such that the optimizer can do a better job etc.